# Python normalized pathname with a special case

Tags: python, debugging, path, directory, normalization

consider the following example

```
#junk path ending with a test file
test = "C:\\test1/test2\test3.txt"
```

with `import os` and `os.path.abspath` in can normalize the pathname

```
test_norm = os.path.abspath(test)
print test_norm    
C:\\test1\\test2\test3.txt'
```

if i split the pathname with `os.path.split` i have the following problem

```
os.path.split(test_norm)
('C:\\test1', 'test2\test3.txt')
```

instead of

```
C:\\test1\\test2 and test3.txt
```

this problem originates from the fact that an user typed with `input_raw` a directory as the example. Can I avoid this with `raw_input`?

Comment: how was test initially set? what did they type in and what are you setting?

Answer (score 2):

Easy: `'\t'` is a tab character. You need to use `'C:\\test1\\test2\\test3.txt'` or `r'C:\test1\test2\test3.txt'`.

Comment: hey @micheael. If some people wronge to write in my software the input_raw as the example. How i can avoid this?

Comment: @Gianni: `raw_input` doesn't process escapes. If someone types `\t\r\n` at the prompt, you will get the string `"\\t\\r\\n"` (or, equivalently and more readably, `r"\t\r\n"`).

Comment: @Michael - you can use `os.path.isfile(what_the_user_input)` to see if the file exists and warn the user.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't escape that final slash so python thinks you want a tab character (\t) not a separator (\\). `test = "C:\\test1/test2\test3.txt"` should be `test = "C:\\test1/test2\\test3.txt"`.